# How can i prevent only html tags which does not include numbers, so how can i allow numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I set validation expression ValidationExpression="<(.|\n)*?>" but it does not give permission to numbers how can i solve it?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator><br />
```

Comment: Sorry, do you want to *disallow* numbers or *require* numbers?

Comment: It should already allow numbers... it actually allows anything delimited by `<` and `>`.

Comment: Actually I want to prevent html tags

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(.|\n)*`, use `\D*`.

Comment: soory I asked the question wrongly, it is ValidationExpression="(.|\n)*,\D*" is it true

Comment: I tried but it does not work I want to prevent only html tags

Comment: @leventkalay92: Stop trying to prevent HTML tags. Instead, just encode them properly using `Server.HtmlEncode`.

Comment: ok but how i can get only words and number in validation expression

Comment: why dont you try Htmlagility pack , that helps me to prevent html tags comes with actual texts.